# Grails - how to pass list of values to a domain class

Tags: grails, dns

I am trying achieve the following SQL using Grails.

```
“Select * from table1 where col1=’COL1’ and col2  in(‘COL2_1’,’COL2_2’,….) and col3=1”
```

I can get the col2 map and not sure how to pass this map to the table1 domain

I try something like this

```
table1.findAllWhere(col1:'COL1', col2 :modelMap.COl2, col3:1)
```

Which is returning null.

I appreciate any help on this

Thanks
Bala

Answer (score 1):

You can use HQL for this in pretty much a direct translation of that:

```
Map params = [col1: 'COL1', col2List: ['COL2_1', 'COL2_2', 'COL2_3'], col3: '1']

TableOne.executeQuery("""
    select t1 
    from TableOne t1 
    where t1.col1 = :col1 and t1.col2 in (:col2List) and t1.col3 = :col3
""", params)
```